# Find maximum value of attribute with Groovy XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

Given xml:

```
<d>
    <r1 dt="2011-06-10">
        <r11 dt="2012-07-10" />
        <r12 rdt="2011-10-11">
            <r121 dt="2010-05-13" />
        </r12>
    </r1>
    <r2>
        <r21 dt="2011-10-10"><n2 ddt="2012-11-31"/>dt</r21>
        <r22 dt="2013-07-10"><n2 ddt="2013-06-31"/>dt</r22>
        <r23 dt="2014-06-10"><n2 ddt="2014-03-31"/>dt</r23>
        <r24 dt="2015-06-10"><n2 ddt="2011-10-31"/>dt</r24>
    </r2>
</d>
```

I need to find value among attributes `dt`, `rdt` and `ddt` that has maximum date using **Groovy XmlSlurper**. In the given example it will be `2015-06-10`. Suppose xml tree structure and deep is unknown (varies). Is it possible to do it using `onliner`, or should I do some iterations in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `s` is string containing xml:

```
def x = new XmlSlurper().parseText(s)
```

Then this will get you a list of all `dt` attribute values

```
def list = x.depthFirst().findAll { it.@dt != "" }​.collect {it.@dt}​​​
```

you can use a similar bit of code to get lists of all `rdt` and `ddt`. Put em all into a single list and then just get max you can do:

```
list.max { a, b -> 
    new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd", a.toString()) <=> new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd", b.toString())
} ​
```

Comment: You probably meant `list.max` when written `l.max`? Anyway thanks, everything worked like a charm.

Comment: @lospejos haha yeah, I was using one letter vars in groovy console for testing, then decided to rename them for the answer. Guess I missed that one, cheers!

Comment: Could you please provide code in case if I need not just a maximum date value (not plain string), but reference to a parent node that contains this maximum date value attribute?

Comment: Well the list here will be a list of instances of the slurpers attribute class (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/slurpersupport/Attributes.html). So if you wanted the parent to lets say the first one, you could do `list[0].parents()`.

Comment: Unfortunately,  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: parents() not implemented yet. This is also present here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/Attributes.html#parents()

Comment: Oh wow. Well `parent()` seems to work. `list[0].parent()​.name()​` gives me `r1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118927/discussion-between-lospejos-and-osasoft).